# CanvasVirtualControl InvalidateRegions Splitted automatically , Why?

Tags: uwp-xaml, win2d

What i have Tried is?
My Xaml Code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">
   
    <Button Content="InvalidateParticularRegion" Height="100" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="0" Click="InvalidateParticularRegion"/>
</Canvas>
```

My C# code:

```
CanvasVirtualControl canvasVirtualControl;
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        canvasVirtualControl = new CanvasVirtualControl();
        canvasVirtualControl.Width = 1486;
        canvasVirtualControl.Height = 610;
        MyCanvas.Children.Add(canvasVirtualControl);
        Canvas.SetLeft(canvasVirtualControl, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(canvasVirtualControl, 100);
        canvasVirtualControl.RegionsInvalidated += CanvasVirtualControl_RegionsInvalidated;
    }


    private void CanvasVirtualControl_RegionsInvalidated(CanvasVirtualControl sender, CanvasRegionsInvalidatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(args.InvalidatedRegions.Count());
        CanvasDrawingSession drawingSession;
        Rect rect = new Rect(args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Left, args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Top, args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Width, args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Height);
        Debug.WriteLine((args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Left + "   " + args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Top + "   " + args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Width + "   " +args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Height));
        using (drawingSession = sender.CreateDrawingSession(rect))
        {
            drawingSession.DrawRectangle((float)rect.X, (float)rect.Y, (float)rect.Width, (float)rect.Height, Colors.Green, 10);
        }
    }

    private void InvalidateParticularRegion(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        canvasVirtualControl.Invalidate(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
        canvasVirtualControl.Invalidate(new Rect(200, 200, 200, 200));
        Debug.WriteLine("prem");
        canvasVirtualControl.Invalidate(new Rect(300, 300, 200, 200));
        Debug.WriteLine("kumar");
    }
```

I had Invalidtae three regions using Invalidate().The first invalidate regions(0,0,100,100) do not intersect with other two regions.The second and third Invalidate regions are (200,200,200,200) and (300,300,200,200) are intersected and they splited into three regions.I had invalidate three regions only ,but totally four regions has been invalidated.I don't know how the second and third regions splitted.Can any explain it how they are splitted and how to stop it?

Comment: This behavior is when you provide multiple drawing areas at once, win2d optimizes the algorithm to avoid drawing repeated areas, but it does not affect the actual Invalid area. If you want to render separately, maybe you can consider using Task.Delay to delay the call of invalidate method.

Comment: how to use Task?..can you provide me some example?

Comment: You can add the [Task.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netcore-3.1) after Invalidate() method to delay the call of next Invalidate() method. For example: `canvasVirtualControl.Invalidate(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));  await Task.Delay(100); canvasVirtualControl.Invalidate(new Rect(200, 200, 200, 200));`